# Disabling IPv6 without tweaking the registry

Tags: networking, windows-8, ip, internet-connection, ipv6

I read an article that disabling IPv6 needs a registry hack. Is there a different way to disable IPv6 without modifying the registry in Windows 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Network and Sharing from the Control Panel. Select "Change adapter settings" on the left sidebar. Then, right click the network device you want to disable IP6 on and select "Properties". Scroll through the list of items to find "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCIP/IPv6)" and uncheck it. Click OK and it will be disabled on that connections.

Notes:

- Windows will disconnect from the network for a few seconds after you hit OK.
- You have to do this on EACH separate connection if you have more than one (multihomed)

Comment: Yep, this disabled IPv6 on that adapter. But like the other guy said, you really shouldn't if at all possible. You're just going to cause problems for yourself later.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this doesn't answer your question, but you might want to reconsider disabling IPv6. Microsoft [states](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.cableguy.aspx):

> From Microsoft's perspective, IPv6 is a mandatory part of the Windows
>   operating system and it is enabled and included in standard Windows
>   service and application testing during the operating system
>   development process. Because Windows was designed specifically with
>   IPv6 present, Microsoft does not perform any testing to determine the
>   effects of disabling IPv6. If IPv6 is disabled on Windows Vista,
>   Windows Server 2008, or later versions, some components will not
>   function.

The only case where disabling IPv6 'solves' anything is when you have a router on the local network who pretends to offer global IPv6 connectivity but doesn't. Common cases are a badly configured router or a Windows machine with Internet Connection Sharing enabled. The real solution in those cases is to fix that broken router. All current and new devices like PCs, tablets and smartphones will use IPv6, and leaving a broken router in the network will cause lots of problems.

Disabling IPv6 in Windows 8 *will* break features. If you give more information about why you are considering disabling IPv6 I'll try to help you find a better solution than disabling IPv6.

Comment: I asked how to disable it, not why I shouldn't disable it.

Comment: Just warning you :-)

Comment: True. I adjusted the answer a bit to acknowledge this. If you give more information about why you want to disable IPv6 I'll try to expand my answer according to that.

Comment: IPV6 enabled on windows 8 makes xampp slow, i mean local development, page load delay more than usual (( too much to be perceptible ))

Comment: imm.hlk: if enabling IPv6 makes your network slow then you have a broken device on your network (i.e. which pretends to be an IPv6 router while not actually being able to route the traffic anywhere) or some software on your machine is broken (i.e. firewall, anti-virus or 'internet security' software which doesn't properly support IPv6). Win8 by itself supports IPv6 just fine without any delays.

Answer (score 0):

There are simpler ways, I'm sure, but this works on a standard Win8 system.
Go to Desktop
Rightclick desktop, choose Personalize
Click Control Panel Home
Click View Network Status and Tasks
Click Ethernet
Click Properties

Now you're looking at pretty much the dialog box you're

Comment: Did you have to rush somewhere and thus couldn't complete your answer?

Comment: Strange ... I don't know what ate the last bit of that sentence.  It was something along the lines of "Now you're looking at pretty much the dialog box you're accustomed to seeing since Windows WayBackWhen"

Comment: Just pointing out that you can edit it. You might already know this, so, yes...